# How can I reference magic methods with PhpDocumentor?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpstorm, phpdoc

I'm documenting my Zend Framework view helpers and controller plugins using phpdoc @method tags to get better code assist in my IDE (PHPStorm). View helpers and controller plugins are called via __invoke() magic methods.

For example, I have a DateTime view helper:

```
class DateTime extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke($dateTimeString, $date = true, $time = true, $seconds = false)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

which is documented as follows:

```
/**
 * @method string dateTime($dateTimeString, $date = true, $time = true, $seconds = false)
 */
class PhpRenderer extends \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer
{

}
```

Instead of repeating the function signature in the @method tag, is there a way to alias or reference the __invoke function? So I wouldn't have to keep the @method tags in sync with the __invoke() method parameters and IDEs could link calls directly to the magic method.

Something like this would be nice:

```
/**
 * @method dateTime \MyLib\View\Helper\DateTime::__invoke
 */
```

If @method could also take a reference to another (magic) method, PHP frameworks could document their magic (__invoke, __call, etc) better and IDEs could link directly to the implementation. Or maybe another tag name should be used for this, e.g. @alias, @call, @invoke.

Comment: As simple as **NO**: 1) there is no such PHPDoc tag and 2) there is no alternative tag that is supported by PhpStorm

Comment: Too bad, this would really be a nice feature since IDEs could then link the method call directly to the invoke method. At the moment, PHPStorm just links to the @method documentation.

Comment: It's an old answer, but this might be what we were looking for: https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html