# How can I replace the PhpRenderer in a ZF2 application

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have extended the PhpRenderer class in my ZF2 application like this:

```
namespace MyLib\View\Renderer;
class PhpRenderer extends \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer
{

}
```

I don't want to add a new rendering strategy, I just extend the PhpRenderer to [add some @method phpdoc for my viewhelpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189400/can-i-use-method-aliasing-with-phpdocumentor).

How can I replace the standard PhpRenderer with my extended PhpRenderer so it will be used to render my viewscripts?

Answer (score 1):

The php renderer is a service inside the service manager. You can override this service directly or do it via the view manager (which instantiates and configures the renderer).

**Override the service**

In your module you define an onBootstrap() method. The "old" php renderer is already registered, you have to redefine it.

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $sm  = $app->getServiceManager();

    $old = $sm->get('ViewRenderer');
    $new = new MyCustomViewRenderer;

    $new->setHelperPluginManager($old->getHelperPluginManager());
    $new->setResolver($old->getResolver());

    $sm->setAllowOverride(true);
    $sm->setService('ViewRenderer', $new);
    $sm->setAllowOverride(false);
}
```

**Override the view manager**

There is an alternative where you can redefine the view manager where the php renderer is instantiated. You have to redefine the view manager's factory for this:

In your application.config.php (note it is the *application* config, as the module config will not work here!)

```
service_manager => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'HttpViewManager' => 'MyModule\Service\HttpViewManagerFactory',
    ),
);
```

Then create your MyModule\Service\HttpViewManagerFactory:

```
use MyModule\View\Http\ViewManager as HttpViewManager;

class HttpViewManagerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create and return a view manager for the HTTP environment
     *
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return HttpViewManager
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return new HttpViewManager();
    }
}
```

And then you can finally update the factory of the php renderer itself:

```
use Zend\Mvc\View\Http\ViewManager as BaseViewManager;

class ViewManager extends BaseViewManager
{
    public function getRenderer()
    {
        if ($this->renderer) {
            return $this->renderer;
        }

        $this->renderer = new MyCustomViewPhpRenderer;
        $this->renderer->setHelperPluginManager($this->getHelperManager());
        $this->renderer->setResolver($this->getResolver());

        $model       = $this->getViewModel();
        $modelHelper = $this->renderer->plugin('view_model');
        $modelHelper->setRoot($model);

        $this->services->setService('ViewRenderer', $this->renderer);
        $this->services->setAlias('Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer', 'ViewRenderer');
        $this->services->setAlias('Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface', 'ViewRenderer');

        return $this->renderer;
    }
}
```

**Conclusion**

The first method instantiates the normal php renderer already, so you instantiate two of them and replace the default with your own.

An alternative is to circumvent the instantiation of the default Zend's php renderer, but you have to do this inside the view manager class. The problem here is you have to redefine the factory for the view manager as well. This sounds as a detour, but it is the only way to get this done.

Comment: I tried your first solution but I ran into some problems. First I changed $old->getResolver()` to `$old->resolver()` since there is no method `getResolver()` in the PhpRenderer. By debugging, I then noticed that the plugins (e.g. FlashMessenger) are not loaded in the new PhpRenderer. Also PhpRenderer::__vars is empty. It seems that these internal plugins and variables are somehow bound to the `Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer` namespace. The debugger shows `*Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer*__vars = null`.

Comment: I wish ZF2 made it easier to replace classes like the PhpRenderer with extended classes. I feel I have to bend over backwards to achieve such a basic task.

Comment: I also tried the second method, but it seems that the `HttpViewManagerFactory::createService()` method never gets called. I did add the factory to application.config.php, as you describe in the first step.

Comment: I put this up for discussion here: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/5573

Answer (score 1):

If all your custom class contains is `@method` declarations then you don't need to replace the php renderer class. Just make sure to use the `@var` docblock and your IDE will know what to do:

Document the type for the `$this` variable in your view files:

```
<!-- in a view file -->
<?php /* @var $this MyLib\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer */ ?>

<?= $this->myCustomViewHelper() ?>
```

Document individual variables or properties for view helpers, classes, etc:

```
class SomeHelper extends AbstractHelper
{
    /** @var \MyLib\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer */
    protected $view;

    public function __invoke()
    {
        $this->view->myCustomViewHelper();
    }
}
```

Comment: That indeed works and I have used `@var` comments already. It's not my favourite solution though, since I have to spread dozens of these and they are a little misleading, since they don't indicate the real type of the PhpRenderer in this case. You get my vote though for a pragmatic solution :).