# Zend Framework 2 - Translation and text domain in views

Tags: php, internationalization, zend-framework2

I'm currently working on translating an existing Zend Framework 2 project that is spread around multiple modules.

My understanding of the translate functionality of ZF2, is that you can have as many translation files, providing each are 'namespaced' to a different `text_domain`. This works fine in practice, with each module having the following in their `module.config.php` file:

```
...
'translator' => array (
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array (
        array (
            'type' => 'phparray',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern' => '%s_default.php',
            'text_domain' => 'ExampleModule'
        ),
    ),
),
...
```

Which adds a `../language/*_default.php` file to the translation list with a `text_domain` of `ExampleModule`. All good so far.

Now, the translator itself needs to know which `text_domain` to pick a translation from and will use `default` if one isn't provided.

So, inside and at the top of all of my view `*.phtml` files, I have:

```
$this->plugin('translate')->setTranslatorTextDomain('ExampleModule');
$this->formLabel()->setTranslatorTextDomain('ExampleModule');
$this->formText()->setTranslatorTextDomain('ExampleModule');
```

Which tells all proceeding `$this->translate()` blocks and form elements which `text_domain` to use.

This is great, and works fine, but it doesn't sit well with the DRY principle in that I have similar code at the top of every view. I attempted to extend the `ViewModel` class so I can pick a different `ViewModel` class in the controller and have the above code already baked in, but the plugins aren't available at that stage.

How would I include the above code on every/most views without having to type it each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching endlessly, I found that the default renderer - `PhpRenderer` - can be accessed via the `onBootstrap` method of `Module.php` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194053/how-can-i-replace-the-phprenderer-in-a-zf2-application)).

As the view scripts are rendered by `PhpRenderer` the `$this` variable points to `PhpRenderer` ([reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.view.php-renderer.scripts.html)). This means that you can attach the code I needed to `Module.php` as below:

```
// Get the default ViewRenderer (PhpRenderer) and setup the correct text domain for derivative plugins
$viewRenderer = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ViewRenderer');
$viewRenderer->plugin('translate')->setTranslatorTextDomain('ExampleModule');
$viewRenderer->formLabel()->setTranslatorTextDomain('ExampleModule');
$viewRenderer->formText()->setTranslatorTextDomain('ExampleModule');
```

As the current namespace matches the `text_domain` I need, the above can be simplified by swapping `'ExampleModule'` with `__NAMESPACE__`.

EDIT: If you're looking for a different `text_domain` per module; you'll need in just one `Module.php`:

```
 $viewRenderer = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ViewRenderer');
    $eventManager->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($e) use ($viewRenderer) {
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        $controllerClass = get_class($controller);
        $moduleNamespace = substr($controllerClass, 0, strpos($controllerClass, '\\'));

        $viewRenderer->plugin('translate')->setTranslatorTextDomain($moduleNamespace);
        $viewRenderer->formLabel()->setTranslatorTextDomain($moduleNamespace);
        $viewRenderer->formText()->setTranslatorTextDomain($moduleNamespace);
    }, 100);
```